# How to make a div appear before an on click event is triggered

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following div

```
<div id="dashboard_welcome">Welcome to the Admin Dashboard</div>
```

That I want to appear before any sort of on click event is triggered and then for this div to go away once a selection has been made.

I created a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5mf989jL/) to help show what I am doing...

As you can see the user requests div shows up first and the `<div id="dashboard_welcome">Welcome to the Admin Dashboard</div>`..never shows up at all.

How can I make the `dashboard_welcome` div show up before the on click event buttons?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't want to show the other divs until they're clicked on, then don't run `first().trigger.click()` on the first div and hide the clickable elements initially:

```
$('.panel_out input').on('click', function () {
    var id_to_show = '#' + this.id.replace('_button', '');
    $(id_to_show).show().siblings().hide();
}); // remove .first().trigger('click');

$('#dashboard_welcome').siblings().hide();
```

https://jsfiddle.net/mha0s0jm/

Comment: Tree for some reason that update messed up the arrow dash I have from the panel_buttons. I had this code `//For the arrow in panel
     $("input.arrowBtn").click(function(){
      $(this).siblings('.arrow-left').remove();
      $("<div class='arrow-left'></div>").insertAfter($(this));
     });`...It now only shows on the first input, but it shows higher than it should be. Any idea why?

Comment: @Paul That's weird. I don't see the arrow button at all, even in your original fiddle. Please open a new question if you're still having issues with the arrow button.

Answer (score 2):

Keep the `<div id="dashboard_welcome">Welcome to the Admin Dashboard</div>` above the `<div class="panel_out">`.

I believe it is the the heading of the section it should be before the panel and not related the any action of the panel.

Updated [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5mf989jL/1/)

Comment: This shows that div, but the user requests div still shows automatically.